# Typescript: can I dynamically generate types within TS itself?

Tags: typescript, redux

I want the types of my redux actions to be statically typed, so I can benefit from typo detection, autocomplete, etc, in code which deals with actions, like reducers etc.

To get this working well, I really need to statically type the structure of every action in my app like so

```
type Actions =
  | { type: 'A_PENDING' }
  | { type: 'A_FULFILLED', payload: { a: number } }
  | { type: 'A_REJECTED', error: Error }
  | { type: 'B_PENDING' }
  | { type: 'B_FULFILLED', payload: { b: number } }
  | { type: 'B_REJECTED', error: Error }
  | { type: 'C_PENDING' }
  | { type: 'C_FULFILLED', payload: { c: number } }
  | { type: 'C_REJECTED', error: Error }
```

However, there is a lot of repetition in writing these types out for all my actions.

I know I can write editor templates to literally generate this code for me, but I've been wondering if there's any 'native' TS way to generate such patterns of type definitions.

I'd imagine a syntax something like this (pseudocode)

```
typegenerator AsyncAction = (BaseString, PayloadType) => 
  | { type: BaseString + '_PENDING' }
  | { type: BaseString + '_FULFILLED' }, payload: PayloadType }
  | { type: BaseString + '_REJECTED' }, error: Error }

type Actions =
  | AsyncAction('A', { a: number })
  | AsyncAction('B', { b: number })
  | AsyncAction('C', { c: number })
```

Does anything like this exist, or am I better off just doing literal code generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's not possible to concatenate strings on a type-level currently. (similar request for feature [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12861))

But the following might make the code less repetitive (if not less repetitive at least more systematically repetitive)

```
type AsyncActionType = "A" | "B";
type AsyncActionPayloads = {
    "A": { a: number },
    "B": { b: string }
}

type PendingActionTypes = {
    "A": "A_PENDING",
    "B": "B_PENDING"
}

type FulfilledActionTypes = {
    "A": "A_FULFILLED",
    "B": "B_FULFILLED"
}

type RejectedActionTypes = {
    "A": "A_REJECTED",
    "B": "B_REJECTED"
}

type AsyncAction = {
    [T in AsyncActionType]: {
        type: PendingActionTypes[T]
    } | {
        type: FulfilledActionTypes[T],
        payload: AsyncActionPayloads[T]
    } | {
        type: RejectedActionTypes[T],
        error: Error
    }
}[AsyncActionType];

type Action =
    { type: "MY_OTHER_NON_ASYNC_ACTION" } |
    { type: "MY_ANOTHER_NON_ASYNC_ACTION", payload: { foo: number } } |
    AsyncAction;
```

[Playground demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20AsyncActionType%20%3D%20%22A%22%20%7C%20%22B%22%3B%0D%0Atype%20AsyncActionPayloads%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22A%22%3A%20%7B%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22B%22%3A%20%7B%20b%3A%20string%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20PendingActionTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22A%22%3A%20%22A_PENDING%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22B%22%3A%20%22B_PENDING%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FulfilledActionTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22A%22%3A%20%22A_FULFILLED%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22B%22%3A%20%22B_FULFILLED%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20RejectedActionTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22A%22%3A%20%22A_REJECTED%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22B%22%3A%20%22B_REJECTED%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AsyncAction%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BT%20in%20AsyncActionType%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20PendingActionTypes%5BT%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%7C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20FulfilledActionTypes%5BT%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20AsyncActionPayloads%5BT%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%7C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20RejectedActionTypes%5BT%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20error%3A%20Error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%5BAsyncActionType%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Action%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22MY_OTHER_NON_ASYNC_ACTION%22%20%7D%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22MY_ANOTHER_NON_ASYNC_ACTION%22%2C%20payload%3A%20%7B%20foo%3A%20number%20%7D%20%7D%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20AsyncAction%3B). Hover over `AsyncAction` you'll see it's a union of all async actions that you would expect. Also try removing `"B": "B_PENDING"` from `PendingActionTypes`, you'll get a compilation error.

Also you see the annoying parts `PendingActionTypes`, `FulfilledActionTypes` and `RejectedActionTypes` can be moved to a different file that can be generated via a nodejs script that reads the file containing `AsyncActionType` and excutes when that file changes

Comment: Thanks and +1, this way of doing it is pretty interesting. This gets almost all the way there to what I thought might be possible, but yeah the fact you still have to manually type out the strings is unfortunate. You answered my question though, it's not possible (yet). Good to know.

Comment: @davnicwil You're welcome! :) Maybe one day when it's possible I'll update this answer by replacing `PendingActionTypes[T]` with `T + "_PENDING"` xD

Answer (score 0):

I feel like posting this answer too because it's closer (actually kinda exact) to your pseudo code. I didn't post this previously because it doesn't reduce the repetitiveness but just displaces it. (maybe makes it more repetitive? idk). If I ignore the `extends "A" | "B"` which demands for consistency and makes it repetitive, I like this solution more.

```
type AsyncAction<T extends "A" | "B", P> = 
    | { type: AddSuffix<T, "PENDING"> }
    | { type: AddSuffix<T, "FULFILLED">, payload: P }
    | { type: AddSuffix<T, "REJECTED">, error: Error }

type Action =
    | AsyncAction<"A", { a: string }>
    | AsyncAction<"B", { b: string }>



type AddSuffix<
    T extends "A" | "B",
    S extends "PENDING" | "FULFILLED" | "REJECTED"
> =
    T extends "A" ?
        S extends "PENDING" ? "A_PENDING" :
        S extends "FULFILLED" ? "A_FULFILLED" :
        S extends "REJECTED" ? "A_REJECTED" :
        never :
    T extends "B" ?
        S extends "PENDING" ? "B_PENDING" :
        S extends "FULFILLED" ? "B_FULFILLED" :
        S extends "REJECTED" ? "B_REJECTED" :
        never : 
    never;
```

[Playground demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20AsyncAction%3CT%20extends%20%22A%22%20%7C%20%22B%22%2C%20P%3E%20%3D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20%7B%20type%3A%20AddSuffix%3CT%2C%20%22PENDING%22%3E%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20%7B%20type%3A%20AddSuffix%3CT%2C%20%22FULFILLED%22%3E%2C%20payload%3A%20P%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20%7B%20type%3A%20AddSuffix%3CT%2C%20%22REJECTED%22%3E%2C%20error%3A%20Error%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Action%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20AsyncAction%3C%22A%22%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%20string%20%7D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20AsyncAction%3C%22B%22%2C%20%7B%20b%3A%20string%20%7D%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AddSuffix%3C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20T%20extends%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20S%20extends%20%22PENDING%22%20%7C%20%22FULFILLED%22%20%7C%20%22REJECTED%22%0D%0A%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20T%20extends%20%22A%22%20%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20S%20extends%20%22PENDING%22%20%3F%20%22A_PENDING%22%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20S%20extends%20%22FULFILLED%22%20%3F%20%22A_FULFILLED%22%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20S%20extends%20%22REJECTED%22%20%3F%20%22A_REJECTED%22%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20never%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20T%20extends%20%22B%22%20%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20S%20extends%20%22PENDING%22%20%3F%20%22B_PENDING%22%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20S%20extends%20%22FULFILLED%22%20%3F%20%22B_FULFILLED%22%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20S%20extends%20%22REJECTED%22%20%3F%20%22B_REJECTED%22%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20never%20%3A%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20never%3B)